# Whitelisted domains in env.php M2.3.6 does not work

Tags: magento2.3, environment-variable

I whitelisted three domains in env.php but when adding a link with a downloadable product still get the error message

> Link URL's domain is not in list of downloadable_domains in env.php

Is the entry not effected immediately?
Any help appreciated.
Thanks
Tristan

Comment: bin/magento downloadable:domains:show check using this command

Comment: This command shows the correct domains!

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it.

1. Add domains WITHOUT http:// or https://
2. In order to take effect empty all cache by bin/magento cache:clean